# Restrict access to a site through another site

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, dns, cpanel

I have been asked the following (Website with Drupal):

```
1. Create a website B
2. Make that website available only through another website A
3. Every first entry to website B happens through website A
   so that google analytics sessions increase in website A
4. Users can´t enter website B unless going through website A first
5. In order for the user to access Website B they want to type a human readable name.
```

What my logic and basic knowledge tells me:

- Suppose website B has IP address of 192.168.58.1
- Suppose website B should have domain name childsite (with no DNS record)
- Suppose the human readable name for website B (initial access) is coolsite
- Suppose website A has domain name fathersite.com

A)

**Website B** will have no human-readable domain (it will just have an IP address), nonetheless every time the user moves around **website B** I will need to find a module to translate that IP address into a human readable name (that does not exist in a DNS but I do own the domain name) for the sake of the user not viewing the IP numeric address on the URL.

B)

Somehow , somewhere I need to translate or rewrite **fathersite.com/childsite** to 192.168.58.1 so that the user is taken to the actual site through the fathersite (hence the fathersite earning to visit in the process).

C)

Previous to B) I´m going to have to tell my DNS server to translate the domain **coolsite.com** to point to **fathersite.com/childsite**.

**How the actually process would be live**

User types in browser: `coolsite.com`
DNS translates that to `fathersite.com/childsite`
When browser tries to access that page within *fathersite.com* it´s .htaccess file (maybe?) will redirect that to " 192.168.58.1" .

Drupal site located in  `192.168.58.1` will have a module (hopefully it exists already) that changes the text in the browser box to 'childsite.com'. Since `childsite.com` is a domain I own but don´t have it pointing to any IP address on my DNS server, if any person tries to access that in a browser they´ll just get a *"The server at childsite.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed"*

Is my logic absolutely wrong? Can this even be done?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done, but you're going to have to set up `DNS` for both. Otherwise when people copy and paste in links they won't work. If somebody is browsing a page, that domain has to be publicly available (or privately if in an internal network).

Essentially what you're looking for though is a login type concept. Even if there's no actual username/password. Have each page of coolsite (include it in a header block) run a bit of `JS` to detect a cookie. If found, do nothing. If not, route back to fathersite portal. When they click on whatever to go to childsite, it `POST`s in a query string value and the receiving page sets the cookie.

So if they try to go to it directly, they don't have the cookie and get bounced to fathersite portal to coolsite, and coolsite is browsable.

Comment: That is a great idea, yes sir.